# Firebase Messaging - Send updated token to Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

So I have the below in my appdelegate but how do I do the TODO part to send the token to Google?

The reason why I don't think it's sending the token to Google is because I can't seem to send a push notification unless I reinstall the app (since then didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken fires and sends the token), then Google gets the token. But my app has been out for years so users gave permission for remote notifications a long time ago. When they install the next update that includes this, how do I get their phones to resend their token to Google? Or am I just not waiting enough time?

```
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    print("Firebase registration token from message delegate: \(String(describing: fcmToken))")
            
            let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken ?? ""]
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
    

    // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
    // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
}


func application(_ application: UIApplication,didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { //data -> String in
        return String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0)
    }

    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .unknown)
}
```

Comment: When the function gets triggered on app startup you can send the device token to your server and link it to the user in order to send targeted notifications later. If you only need to send notification to all users you don’t need to complete the TODO part otherwise if you need to send notifications to a specific user (like messaging apps) then you have to handle the tokens server side.

Comment: @slimshadystark oh ok I see so the TODO part is only back to your server not back to Google. That makes sense now. Thank you

Comment: "how do I get their phones to resend their token to Google"  What do you mean by sending a token to Google?  You want to send a token to Google as a company?  Or you want to send it to the Cloud Firestore database or something?